# create dataframe list of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My code is as follows,

```
sid = ["592009","478299","621403","112501","250217","1000060","1002776"]
sids = pd.DataFrame()
for i in sid:
    r = requests.get(f"https://frapi.marketsmojo.com/stocks_quality/cardinfo?sid={i}")
    js = r.json()["data"]["quality_tbl"]["list"]
    ratios = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js)
    #ratios.columns = ratios.columns[1]
    sids= sids.append(ratios)
```

Here I am looping through list of company with number of sid_id, I need to create a dataframe, from the list of sid_ID present.

Sample of the output is as follows,

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| Net Interest Income Growth (5y) | 18.80% |
| Net Profit Growth (5y) | 20.55% |
| Advance to Deposit | 86.55% |
| Capital Adequacy Ratio (Tier 1) | 15.58% |
| Gross NPA (latest) | 0.81% |
| Gross NPA (avg) | 1.19% |
| Coverage Ratio (avg) | 72.27% |
| Cost to Income (avg) | 40.16% |
| Net Interest Margin (avg) | 4.54% |
| Operating Profit to Assets (avg) | 5.98% |
| ROA (avg) | 1.75% |

This output is from 1 iteration of loop. How to get the output for all iteration as.

| name | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Net Interest Income Growth (5y) | 18.80% | 19.80% | 18.80% |
| Net Profit Growth (5y) | 20.55% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Advance to Deposit | 86.55% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Capital Adequacy Ratio (Tier 1) | 15.58% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Gross NPA (latest) | 0.81% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Gross NPA (avg) | 1.19% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Coverage Ratio (avg) | 72.27% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Cost to Income (avg) | 40.16% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Net Interest Margin (avg) | 4.54% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| Operating Profit to Assets (avg) | 5.98% | 20.1% | 23.8% |
| ROA (avg) | 1.75% | 20.1% | 23.8% |

how to change the for loop to get the desired output. Or use list and get it is as dataframe?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create list of `Series` first and then pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and `keys` for columns names by `sid`s:

```
sid = ["592009","478299","621403","112501","250217","1000060","1002776"]
dfs = []
for i in sid:
    r = requests.get(f"https://frapi.marketsmojo.com/stocks_quality/cardinfo?sid={i}")
    js = r.json()["data"]["quality_tbl"]["list"]
    #create Series with index by name column
    ratios = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js).set_index('name')['value']
    dfs.append(ratios)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=sid).reset_index()
print (df)
```